# How to check whether the point is at end of visual line when `visual-line-mode` is on?

Tags: elisp

`(eolp)` works only for "hard" line wraps, and I'd like to be able to check whether I'm at the end of *screen* line.  I'd think that looking at the source code of `end-of-visual-line` would help, but it didn't: it uses a built-in function `vertical-motion`, and digging into C sources is not something I'd prefer to do.  (Of course, I could save point position, go to `end-of-visual-line`, compare the point position with the saved one, but is there a better way?)

This would be quite useful, especially that I could hit `C-t` at the end of visual line and not be surprised;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way, but I think your idea to save point position and compare with point at the end of the visual line is reasonable.  Lots of things that behave like pure functions in Emacs actually work by changing state like this and restoring it on exit. The `save-excursion` special form is designed for this kind of pattern:

```
(defun end-of-visual-line-p ()
  (= (point)
     (save-excursion
       (end-of-visual-line)
       (point))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was thinking about something similar (modulo wrapping *everything* in `save-excursion`, which doesn't change much).  I guess I'll just do it this way, and possibly advice `eolp` (and `bolp`, for that matter) so that `C-t` works properly.